# How to specify default values when loading files using yaml?

Tags: ruby, yaml

I saved a object of class Foo using foo.to_yaml. Now i added an instance variable to the Foo class with default value set to 0 in the initializer method. now when I try to load the object from yaml file the instance variable is set to nil.

Is there some way in which I can set it to 0 if the the yaml file doesnt contain any value for that instance variable?

Is there some callback method that is called on object after it has been loaded from disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create reader method for that variable like

```
def your_instance_variable
    return "default" unless @your_instance_variable
    @your_instance_variable
end
```

P.S.
I was doing some task with object serialization some time ago and AFAIK Marshal.dump/load was much faster